# cannot merge streams in aws kinesis zeppelin notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, apache-zeppelin, flink-sql

I am trying to merge two streams using the attribute seq_num, this is also the primary key. I am not able to accomplish this as the seq_num on the two streams is not synced,
what can I do to sync them?

I am using AWS Zeppelin for this analysis and this is the code.

```sql
SELECT * FROM test1
INNER JOIN test
ON test1.seq_num = test.seq_num
group by t.seq_num FLOOR(("test1".ROWTIME - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 10 TO SECOND);
```